# How can I convert an Access Report to a Crystal Report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-access, crystal-reports

I have Access 2003, and Crystal Reports 10 (the one that comes with VS2008 Pro). How can I convert the access reports into Crystal Reports? It doesn't have to be perfect, just anything to lessen the load on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe http://www.access2crystal.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Our AccessToCR that can help you to convert your Access reports to Crystal Reports. Our url is http://www.microtools.us/.